# There is no backup files on basis of max filesize with RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, windows, log4j

There are two applications running and writing to same trace log file.
After it reaches the max file size no backup files are created.

This issue is happening only in **Windows** platform.
How can we solve this issue so that backup files are created as expected?

Note : Same scenario works in Linux platform.

I have following code:

```
void configure(){

       if (getProperty(Space.SystemOpts.TraceIsActive).booleanValue()) {                logger.setLevel(Level.toLevel(getProperty(SystemOpts.Level).getStringValue()));            } else {                logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
                }
                if(getProperty(Space.SystemOpts.TraceOnStdOut).booleanValue()){
                    logger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(appenderLayout));
                }
                RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(appenderLayout, getCurrentTracePath());            fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(getIntegerProperty(SystemOpts.MaxBackupIndex));            fileAppender.setMaxFileSize(getProperty(SystemOpts.MaxFileSize).getStringValue());            logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
    }
```

Comment: can you post you log4j.xml file